# Subgroups with fixed number of elements of $S_n$ with two generators and no fixed points.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, combinations

Let's $p$ be a prime number, $c=\frac{(p-1)p(p+1)}{2}$

For which $n$ there is a subgroup $G$ of the permutation group of $n$ elements $S_n$ such that $G$ has $c$ elements (there is $c=\#G$), two generators (there is $\exists x,y\in S_n:\ \langle x,y\rangle=G$) and his elements differents from the identity doesn't fix any points (there is $\forall g\in G\setminus\{Id\}\ \forall k\in\{1,\dots,n\}\ g(k)\neq k$)?

It's part of a big problem that I'm trying to resolve and not being an expert (not at all) in these type of mathematic I don't have any idea to how to proceed. Even some suggestion or literature reference will be fantastic.

Sorry for my bad English, I added all the formal statement for help you understand what I'm trying to ask.

EDIT(someone asked for a bit more of context):I wish to know the cardinality of a discrete set of points in a space on which the group of automorphism of the space (having cardinality $c$ and being generated by two elements) act as a group of permutation. Those I hoped to find one and only one $n$ such that my group of automorphism can be imbedded in $S_n$, being able in this way to deduce that I had $n$ points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last condition means that $G$ is semiregular. In particular, $n$ must be a multiple of $|G|=c$. This is also sufficient. Just take $G$ to be any $2$-generated group of order $c$. When $n=|G|$, consider the regular action of $G$ on itself. More generally, for $n=k|G|$, take $k$ copies of this, and then take the diagonal subgroup. (In other words, you have one copy of $G$ acting regularly simultaneously on $k$ sets of size $|G|$.)

Comment: But can we be sure that for each integer k there is a subgroup generated by two elements of $S_{ck}$ ?

Comment: Why not the cyclic group?

Comment: If you really want the group to be properly $2$-generated, then you can take say the index $2$ subgroup of AGL(1,p) (which has order $p(p-1)/2$), direct product with a cyclic group of order $p+1$. This is not cyclic but $2$-generated, for $p\geq 5$.
For $p=3$, just take any non-cyclic group of order $12$. For $p=2$, there is no example, since $c=3$ in this case.

Comment: In these way I have that exits a 2-generated group of order $c$, but not in which $S_n$ it can be imbedded.

I edited my question with a bit more of context.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I have answered your question completely, as it posed now.

Let's look at an example. Take $p=2$, then $|G|=c=3$, $G$ is cyclic of order $3$.


Now, if you want to embed $G$ in $S_n$ as a semiregular subgroup, then you need $n$ to be a multiple of 3.
Given $n=ck=3k$, it is easy to do so.

Take $x=(1~2~3)(4~5~6)\cdots(n-2~n-1~n)$, and then $y\in\langle x\rangle$.

Then $G=\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x\rangle$, and $G$ has the properties that you want.

Comment: So, there is more than one $n$. If you want a unique $n$, probably the most natural additional hypothesis is that $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$. In which case, we will easily get that $c=n$.

Comment: Ok, now everything it's clear. Thank you very much!